# Documenting class-level variables in Python

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docstring, autodoc, sphinx-napoleon

I am trying to document a Python class that has some class-level member variables, but I could not get it appropriately documented using reST/Sphinx.

The code is this:

```py
class OSM:
    """Some blah and examples"""
    url = 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter'  # URL of the Overpass API
    sleep_time = 10  # pause between successive queries when assembling OSM dataset
```

But I get this output (see the green circled area, where I would like to have some text describing both variables, as above).

[image]

I apologize for the blurring, but part of the example is somewhat sensitive

Comment: You need to document them in the docstring, not with code comments. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several options to document class level variables.

1. Put a comment that starts with `#:` before the variable, or on the same line. (Uses only autodoc.)

   Perhaps the easiest choice. If needed you can customize the value using `:annotation:` option. If you want to type-hint the value use `#: type:`.
2. Put a docstring after the variable.

   Useful if the variable requires extensive documentation.

   > [For module data members and class attributes, documentation can either be put into a comment with special formatting (using a #: to start the comment instead of just #), or in a docstring after the definition. Comments need to be either on a line of their own before the definition, or immediately after the assignment on the same line. The latter form is restricted to one line only.](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autoattribute)
3. Document the variable in the class docstring. (Uses sphinx-napoleon extension, [shown in the example](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/example_google.html#example-google-style-python-docstrings).)

   This has the drawback that the variable's value will be omitted. Since it's a class level variable your IDE's static type checker may complain if you don't prefix the variable with `cls.` or `class_name.`. The distinction is however convenient because instance variables can also be documented in the class docstring.

The following example shows all three options. The `.rst` has additional complexity to illustrate the needed`autodoc` functionalities. Type hints were included in all cases but can also be omitted.

```py
class OSM:
    """Some blah and examples"""

    #: str: URL of the Overpass API.
    url = 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter'
    #: int: pause between successive queries when assembling OSM dataset.
    sleep_time = 10


class OSM2:
    """Some blah and examples.

    Attributes:
        cls.url (str): URL of the Overpass API.
    """

    url = 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter'

    sleep_time = 10
    """str: Docstring of sleep_time after the variable."""
```

Corresponding `.rst`

```
OSM module
==========

.. automodule:: OSM_module
    :members:
    :exclude-members: OSM2

    .. autoclass:: OSM2
        :no-undoc-members:
        :exclude-members: sleep_time

        .. autoattribute:: sleep_time
            :annotation: = "If you want to specify a different value from the source code."
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: I tested suggestion #1 and worked like a charm. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This also works, if you're ok with suppressing a silly linter rule.

```
class OSM2:
    sleep_time = 10;  """str: Inline docstring of sleep_time after the variable."""
```