# Problems with generating documentation of class variables with sphinx

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, docstring, class-variables

I have a very simple class with 2 class variables and I want to effectively document the class variables -

```
class AzimuthalRhoPhi(Azimuthal):
    r"""
    Attributes:
        rho (scalar, ``np.ndarray``, ``ak.Array``, etc.): The $\rho$ coordinate(s).
        phi (scalar, ``np.ndarray``, ``ak.Array``, etc.): The $\phi$ coordinate(s).
    """

    rho: ScalarCollection
    phi: ScalarCollection
```

The docstring above does work but sphinx renders the class variables individually (and automatically) too. Rendered documentation (notice the extra `rho` and `phi` automatically generated by sphinx) -

[image]

This is the `.rst` file -

```
.. automodule:: vector._methods
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
   :private-members:
```

Going through the following StackOverflow posts -

- [How to remove static class variable using automodule with Sphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61702285/how-to-remove-static-class-variable-using-automodule-with-sphinx)
- [Documenting class-level variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64796801/documenting-class-level-variables-in-python)

I discovered that there are 4 ways in which I can accomplish this -

1. Use comments above the class variable
2. Use inline docstring
3. Exclude the class variable from `.rst` file
4. Use `cls.variable_name` format

---

1. Using comments above the class variable

Code -

```
class AzimuthalRhoPhi(Azimuthal):

    #: scalar, ``np.ndarray``, ``ak.Array``, etc.: The $\rho$ coordinate(s).
    rho: ScalarCollection

    #: scalar, ``np.ndarray``, ``ak.Array``, etc.: The $\phi$ coordinate(s).
    phi: ScalarCollection
```

Rendered documentation -

[image]

Notice how it type annotates the variables with `Any` which I do not want. Plus, having all the documentation related to the class in the docstring makes it much more accessible, which makes me not want to use this method.

2. Use inline docstring

Code -

```
class AzimuthalRhoPhi(Azimuthal):

    rho: ScalarCollection
    r"""scalar, ``np.ndarray``, ``ak.Array``, etc.: The $\rho$ coordinate(s)."""

    phi: ScalarCollection
    r"""scalar, ``np.ndarray``, ``ak.Array``, etc.: The $\phi$ coordinate(s)."""
```

Rendered documentation -

[image]

This method raises the exact same problems which were present in the first method.

3. Exclude the class variables from `.rst` file

Code -

```
.. automodule:: vector._methods
   :members:
   :exclude-members: AzimuthalRhoPhi
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
   :private-members:

   .. autoclass:: AzimuthalRhoPhi
      :exclude-members: rho, phi
```

Rendered documentation -

[image]

Works like a charm! BUT!

- Brings the class to the top of the documentation
- I have a lot of such classes and doing this manually for every class feels redundant.

4. Use `cls.variable_name` format

Code -

```
class AzimuthalRhoPhi(Azimuthal):
    r"""
    Attributes:
        cls.rho (scalar, ``np.ndarray``, ``ak.Array``, etc.): The $\rho$ coordinate(s).
        cls.phi (scalar, ``np.ndarray``, ``ak.Array``, etc.): The $\phi$ coordinate(s).
    """

    rho: ScalarCollection
    phi: ScalarCollection
```

Rendered documentation -

[image]

Does not work :(

---

Is there a way to hide the autogenerated doc of class variables? I only want to keep the docs written in the docstring but sphinx duplicates them in a way. Or do I have to choose one of the four methods mentioned above?

Comment: Do you use `:undoc-members:`? I get similar results with that option.

Comment: Yes, apologies, I should have mentioned that on the top. I am using that as some of my classes and functions are not documented.

Comment: So if you remove `:undoc-members:`, do you get the wanted output for the `AzimuthalRhoPhi` class?